# Am I correctly changing the indicative to subjunctive?

Tags: subjunctives

To convey contrary-to-fact or unreal situations, I want to change the following indicative sentences to the subjunctive. Am I doing this correctly?

> I held the phone as if I **was** holding a bomb that could explode anytime.
>   I held the phone as if I ***were*** holding a bomb that could explode anytime.
>
> As I walked through the battlefield, it felt as if I **was** walking through quicksand.
>   As I walked through the battlefield, it felt as if I ***were*** walking through quicksand.

Comment: In informal English both are accepted. In formal English only "**were**" is acceptable.

Comment: I'd avoid the term 'indicative'. With one 'odd' exception, mood in English is marked by the modal auxiliary verbs, "can", "may", "must" etc. The one 'odd' exception is the "were" such as in your examples, which is an isolated 'irrealis' mood form. The subjunctive is a kind of clause construction headed by a plain form verb, e.g. "It is vital I **be** kept informed".

Comment: You can *drop by anytime*, but a bomb might explode *at any moment*.

Comment: @BillJ we can contrast between a semantic sense and a syntactic sense. Semantically an indicative verb might be used in conjunction with a modal verb. Syntactically, there is a limited subjunctive mood.

Comment: "Indicative" is a verbal category, i.e. syntactic. You could call many of the ordinary non-subjunctives "indicative" if you liked, but it does no work and hence the term is not needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples are correct, although the subjunctive or irrealis *were* form is optional.  As BillJ has suggested, it is arguably a bit pointless or misleading to think of the isolated survival of the "were" form as constituting a full-fledged subjunctive mood.  This would put the other 99% of verb forms into a no-man's-land where no one can say whether they are indicative or subjunctive - particularly because virtually none of the uses of irrealis "were" are mandatory (the main exception being in inverted subordinate clauses: "Were I in New Zealand, I would visit you").

While "was" and "were" are both used to express unreality, "was" is considered less formal, "were" preferable in formal contexts.

A minor point of interest regarding these specific sentences is that usually an unreal past-tense form refers to non-past time (whereas the past perfect is used for unreal reference to past time), but in your examples, the unreal pasts refer to past time.  This is noted as an oddity of "as if" sentences by Jesperson (who suggests that for this reason the "was" form is preferable where the verb refers to past time) and Huddleston & Pullum (who say that the past perfect is usually an alternative in such sentences but that either the simple past or the irrealis is much more common).   (To complicate matters, some speakers use "as if" plus irrealis even when referring to a real past rather than an unreal one.  This is arguably a hypercorrection, and here the past perfect doesn't normally work.)

References: Huddleston & Pullum, *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Cambridge University Press, 2002), pp1151-3.  Jespersen, O., *Essentials of English Grammar* (Allan and Unwin, 1933; Routledge, 1994), 24.2(7), p257.

Comment: Do you have an example of using "as if" + irrealis with a real past event? It's not entirely clear what that would mean

Comment: H&P's example is "*As the trooper left the room, the gambler turned to the army girl with an odd expression, as though he were remembering painful things*" .  (Admittedly that's "as though", but "as if" could be used too.) H&P's comment is that the example "doesn't imply that he wasn't remembering painful things: on the contrary, it suggests that he was or appeared to be" - making it at least arguably a hypercorrection.

Comment: so in that case, is H&P suggesting it should be the realis/indicative "was"?

Comment: Yes, essentially.  They don't quite go that far (they're descriptivists and this use of "were" is probably quite common) - but they say that "were" here has the "flavour of hypercorrection" and they also say that "was" in such sentences wouldn't traditionally have been stigmatised.  Some speakers, anxious not to be accused of neglecting the "were" form, now feel "was" to be stigmatised even in instances where it is traditionally considered correct - resulting in hypercorrection.

Comment: strange. It seems like "were" should be correct because there is uncertainty (irrealis). It isn't established whether the gambler is remembering painful things or not.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Is it okay to use the subjunctive "were" to also imply contrary-to-fact statements? For example: Do not talk of him as if he were a mad explorer. (He is not a mad explorer).

Comment: Yes, indeed you can.

Comment: @rjpond Thank you so much. I've been studying the subjunctive mood to apply it correctly and it seems that the mood can also be used to express wishes. Like, I wish he were younger. Is it okay to use the mood in a sentence like this one: I only wished it was all a dream. (Is it okay to use "were" here?)